# How do I determine whether pipes (water, electricity, gas) are buried in basement concrete?

Tags: concrete, basement, pipe, safety

I would like to drill two 2.5″-deep holes for 5/8″ bolts (64mm x 16mm) in the basement floor. The two holes will be used for a (bicycle) floor anchor.

How do I determine whether pipes (water, electricity, gas) are buried in basement concrete?

Most critically, there is a gas line that runs from one corner of the basement to the heating furnace in the other corner. I can see that line overhead, resting on the wooden beams. Does that mean there won't be another line buried?

As a last resort, is there much safety to be gained from drilling 1mm, vacuuming, and inspecting, before drilling again?

Comment: Do any pipes or cables seem to run down a wall to the floor?  If the furnace is the only thing on gas, there should only be one line.

Comment: Typically, a basement floor is a slab.  It's not thick like a foundation.  It would be pretty unusual for something like that to be embedded in concrete.  Pipes would run under the slab.  I just checked my slab and it's less than 2" thick.

Comment: @JimmyJames I'm afraid I'm ignorant of the details here. What is the prevalent system? The concrete under the walls must surely be (a lot) more than 2″-thick. Are you saying that in the middle, between these 1ft-thick (or so) concrete frame under the walls, there is only a 2″-slab of concrete?

Comment: For residential construction, yes - the basement floor is not taking industrial loads.

Comment: @crip659 Nowhere are gas and electricity pipes near the basement floor. They "descend from above" to the water heater and the furnace, but the main water pipe rises from the floor in a corner of the basement.

Comment: @JonCuster Is the "in-between" concrete worth considering to be used to attach a floor anchor? Cracking the anchor out of it would still be a major undertaking, no?

Comment: If that corner is close/facing the street, probably nothing under the floor.  Usually if under the floor stuff goes in a straight line.  Floor slabs usually at least 3 or 4 inches.

Comment: Sure, it’s just the floor won’t take a giant machine on it…

Comment: @Sam The only pipes I would expect to be under the slab would be sewage.  Are you trying to secure this from theft?  Is this an apartment building?

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that anyone would put pipes _in_ the floor. They'd be too hard to fix/replace being embedded in the concrete like that with little advantage. If there are pipes, they'd be _under_ the floor, but even that's not too common because in most cases the basement is done before all that so plumbing, electricity, etc. is usually all done from above with the exception of sewers/drains, etc.

Comment: @gnicko That's as helpful as any suggestion I've read so far. Please consider writing it as an answer. You're also making me wonder if the office that grants building permits in my jurisdiction would be able to give me a definitive answer. They may have a record of the code that was in place, and those may rule out burying pipes in the foundation.

Comment: @JimmyJames It's a house, not an apartment building. But when I'm away for even a couple of days, I take my laptop with me, and my TV is worthless for a thief. Still I continue to worry whether a thief will go in and use power tools on my bicycles' locks (which are locked just so that they are not rideable), or just carry them locked. I want to at least lock my one or two most cherished bicycles outside of the garage and in the basement, while making it just a little bit harder to steal them by locking them to an anchor to concrete.

Comment: Have you considered attaching anchors a wall instead?

Comment: @JimmyJames That's what I'm doing in the garage (though I unfortunately muddied that question by burying it in the middle of a larger question—see Q#3 here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/256544/115116). In the garage I have wall space to play with. In the basement the walls that are still free are scarce. Plus that seems to only compound the problem since it seems it's more, not less, likely for surprise pipes to be in walls.

Comment: I'm not going to tell you to do it if you aren't comfortable but if it's a poured concrete foundation, I think you'd know.  Embedding a pipe or electrical line in a foundation where it's impossible to fix or replace (and likely compromises the structure) would be insane/idiotic. Through, sure, but not lengthwise. I've drilled holes in my foundation with a rotary hammer to hang things and never thought twice about it.  If the foundation is cinder-block or something else, maybe.

Comment: One way to find out would be to hire a SUE company with ground penetrating radar.

Comment: crazy but happened to me although I am not a believer. I sold an old house back in the day with no blueprints & the new owner requested to know before a buy where in the basement (under concrete) & on the property are all the pipes. so he hired a shaman and they both came by. that shaman took two bent metal rods/wires and begin the search while I was ROFLing on the floor in my mind. shaman found it, the buyer bought it and after the reconstruction, we met by chance so I was curious how accurate that con man was. It turned out he was off by only 2-3cm in some places with bad feng shui or what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my limited experience, the only things I've seen buried in basement floors have been the lines from oil tanks to burners (so the burner can be gravity -fed from the tank). Those run thru either conduit or some form of hose, and in my area you can often (but not always) see a cutline in the slab from when this was installed. There are ways to trace this line, basically by hooking it up to a transmitter and using a short-range receiver to track the resulting "antenna). I don't know whether the "Dig Safe" folks will do in-basement tracing or if you'd need to hire someone or buy the equipment.

I got rid of my oil heat, and all the other utilities go thru walls or ceilings. That doesn't guarantee nobody did something "creative' on your property.

Answer (score 1):

Whether there are any pipes embedded in the concrete depends on building style & type of building. Usually, in a North American house built of wood on a concrete foundation, the foundation and slabs are poured after the drain/sewage and water service entry since they have to be below the frost line, and everything else is completed afterwards. A slab is usually 6in thick, and the top of pipes underneath it may touch the bottom of the slab.

So look around the basement, trace all water, gas and electrical lines: if it's underground and embedded there will be an exit/entry point somewhere.

That's the speculation part. Now to the specifics of your question:

> How do I determine whether pipes (water, electricity, gas) are buried in basement concrete?

- obtain building drawings. These may be available from previous owners or the city
- perform a concrete scan. There are specialized services that perform just that for any drilling: they look for gas, water, electrical, other plumbing, rebar and tensions lines, which are common in concrete structures.

> is there much safety to be gained from drilling 1mm, vacuuming, and inspecting, before drilling again?

If you puncture or scrape the pipe or jacket it's too late. So unless you know it runs in a sleave this approach is not effective. This might work if you have better visibility and for that you should use a wider drill bit. Also requires a degree in archeology.

> will be used for a (bicycle) floor anchor

Unless you are close to the exit point of such a line, which you would see, it is very likely that the lines are at least 1in buried. SO you could roughen up the concrete, and add a cement build-up for the anchors. Or use adhesives for a wooden base, and screw into the base.

Comment: Basement slabs are usually 4" thick, or occasionally 5. 6" is massive overkill more suited to a heavy-duty driveway slab.

Answer (score 0):

I have one of those metal and electricity detectors. Works very well.

It even finds the single drywall screws.

I tested it on a wall where I already knew the mains cable was so I knew how it behaved, this was also how I worked out that it was finding screws…

Comment: Is this the type of device you're describing? https://www.amazon.ca/Stud-Finder-Sensor-Wall-Scanner/dp/B07YKRY4HN/  Is a "metal and electricity detector" simply an advanced stud finder?